# HTML/Bootstrap - Media query issues

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In my project, I implement a navbar using bootstrap, and within that nav bar I have div. This div contains all the images I want on my navbar. I aim to make this navbar responsive.

I use a media query to check whether the screen is a certain size, and if so I aim to move the div's position. However when I rescale my screen, the div does not move position.

Here is my code:

```
 <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
          <div class="navItems" style="position: relative; left: 470px;">
             <img src="{% static 'instaicon.png' %}" style="position: absolute; left: -60px; top: 10px;" width="25px" height="25px">
             <img src="{% static 'line007.png' %}" style="position: absolute; top: -23px; left: -70px;" width="110px" height="120px">
             <img src="{% static 'instatext.png' %}" width="110px" height="45px">
          </div>
 </nav>
```

CSS MEDIA QUERY:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navItems {
      position: absolute;
      left: 3px;
    }
  }
```

Anybody know the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, remove the inline styles. They cause things like this to happen. What is going on here is that the inline style is ALWAYS overriding the external stylesheet.

You're also absolutely positioning items in your nav bar, which you don't want to do (I think). You can use flexbox to automatically space these items out.

Try the following HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
 <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
          <div class="navItems">
             <img src="{% static 'instaicon.png' %}" id="img1" width="25px" height="25px">
             <img src="{% static 'line007.png' %}" id="img2" width="110px" height="120px">
             <img src="{% static 'instatext.png' %}" width="110px" height="45px">
          </div>
 </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    nav .navItems {
      /*No need to state the same position again. The default style will add that*/
      left: 3px;
    }
  }

/*The styles below act as the default style*/
.navItems {
      position: absolute;
      left: 470px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;/*Or maybe use 'center' instead*/
    }
```

You can use the image id's I added to add some `margin-top` if needed, in the external stylesheet. As I saw you added some `top` before.

Comment: Hello, I have pasted the exact code in, however the div doesn't move positions

Comment: That is all the code I am using for my navbar which I have pasted from your code snippet.

Comment: @eweee Try the CSS again. It seems that mediaqueries do not override default CSS, so I made it more specific by adding `nav` in front of it.

Comment: Oh it has worked haha. Can you please explain what you have done with the code in your answer? How does it work?

Comment: @eweee I removed all the inline CSS, which you will want to do anyways, unless there is no other option. And to fix it I merely was more specific in the CSS with the mediaquery. CSS looks at all of the rules and decides which one to use based on how specific it is. `body .elementParent. .thisElement` is more specific than `.thisElement` and that causes CSS to use the first one. The display flex didn't really work out as you haven't specified a width to `.navItems`, but when you do, the images should space out nicely by themselves!

Comment: Oh one more thing. When the media query is executed, the nav bar shortens in height

Comment: Do you know how to keep the nav bars height the same when the media query is executed?

Comment: @eweee You could always set the height to be whatever you want in the default css. `height: 120px;`